# SSHd not starting on CentOS 8.1

Tags: centos, ssh, centos8

I have centos 8.1.1911 (core)

I can't get opensshd to run. I have dnf.

I removed it `dnf remove openssh-server`
then reinstalled `dnf install openssh-server`

`systemctl start sshd`

> job for sshd.service failed for because hte control process exited with error code.

Going through the /var/log/messages log and I see a possible error 
I did `sshd -t` and got the same error, error is:

> Failed to seed from getrandom: Function not implemented

journalctl -xe and systemctl status sshd.service show no other failures

> sshd.service main process exited code=exited status=255/n/a
>   Failed to start openssh server daemon

I did `dnf remove openssh-server` and tried again, still no luck

Removed /etc/ssh folder
`rm -rf /etc/ssh`
To wipe away any bad config and tried again. No luck

Care to advise? Does the centos 8.1.1911 just simply have no way to do this yet?

I saw a comment online to try this:
`mkdir -p /var/run/sshd`

For what I believe for PID file generation but having no luck still.

Comment: Run `tail -f /var/log/messages` and then open a new terminal and run `systemctl start sshd`? Add the output of the first command to your question.

Comment: See https://snipboard.io/vfLlEc.jpg

Comment: https://snipboard.io/H2NlC6.jpg

Comment: More logs https://snipboard.io/EFTtAn.jpg

Comment: is this a  lxc container? See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1812120

Comment: It was a centos 7 Virtual server that was working then i upgraded to centos 8.1, restarted and openssh now fails to start

Comment: There might be a lxc container on backend, how do i backport getrandom syscall to centos 7 version?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason could be when you upgraded the OS from CentOS 7 to CentOS 8 some of the code and commands that might have been defined in the sshd_config which are not compatible with CentOS 8. To know more check the access.log in /var/log PATH. Reinstalling sshd or openssh server doesn't remove the complete instance. Due to that, it may not work in many situations. The best way is to check the logs and sshd_config file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little too late but if the problem is the result of a dist upgrade it's probably a kernel problem, you must upgrade your kernel version.
Check yours with

```
uname -a
```

if =< 3.x you should try an upgrade